# SvelteKit use:enhance doesn't work and fully reloads the page

Tags: forms, svelte, sveltekit

I'm new to SvelteKit and trying to build a simple todo app with a MongoDB database. I followed the tutorials and implemented a form to add todos like so:

```html
 <form
      action="?/create"
      method="POST"
      class="flex flex-col gap-5 justify-center items-center w-2/3 mx-auto"
      use:enhance
    >
      <div class="w-2/3">
        <label class="block text-sm text-gray-500" for="todo"> Title </label>
        <input
          class="border border-gray-300 w-full rounded-md shadow-sm hover:border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-500 transition duration-100 ease-linear p-1 text-gray-700"
          type="text"
          name="title"
          bind:value={title}
        />
      </div>
      <div class="w-2/3">
        <label class="block text-sm text-gray-500" for="todo">
          Description
        </label>
        <textarea
          rows="4"
          class="w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm hover:border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-500 transition duration-100 ease-linear p-1 text-gray-700"
          name="desc"
          bind:value={desc}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button
          class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-8 py-2 rounded-md font-semibold text-lg hover:bg-blue-600 transition duration-100 shadow-xl"
        >
          Create
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

As you see, I am using the use:enhance directive that should prevent the form from reloading the page. When submitted, the form calls the actions object on my "+page.server.js" file, like so:

```js
export const actions = {
  create: async ({ cookies, request }) => {
    const data = await request.formData();
    if (data.get("title").length === 0) {
      return fail(400, {
        error: true,
        message: "Title can't be empty",
      });
    }
    if (data.get("desc").length === 0) {
      return fail(400, {
        error: true,
        message: "Description can't be empty",
      });
    }
    const todo = {
      title: data.get("title"),
      description: data.get("desc"),
    };
    try {
      await createTodo(todo);
    } catch (err) {
      return fail(422, {
        description: "wrong",
      });
    }
  },
};
```

This should be working fine, but my form refreshes each time I submit it, meaning I get a full page reload and the animations don't work (along with other stuff that might be implemented in the future). What is the cause of this? Is it expected behavior and I am missing something?

Comment: Does the dev tools console/network panel or Vite console show any issues?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any issues with this code nor can I reproduce this.

There may be some other code interfering, e.g. a layout's `load` function or a global [hook](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks).

Answer (score 1):

It was actually a bug on the `load` function, setting the state of the store and the browser warned me about an error.

Pretty strange behavior and really hard to spot when you are a beginner with Svelte. I think these behaviors should be documented.

Comment: If you found a bug or think some documentation is missing, report it [on GitHub](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit) (if no issue for that already exists of course).

Answer (score 0):

You should not submit the form. It should be form.requestSubmit